# ReactJS: Create image id when clicked

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, onclick

The following code displays a list of images on a webpage using React JS:

```
this.searchResultsList = this.searchResults.map(function(photo){
    return <div className="dataSetBox" key={photo.toString()}><img src={photo} alt="Image" height="350" width="450" margin="15px" border= "10" onClick={() => imageClick(id = "border")} /></div>;
})
```

When an image is clicked on the webpage, I want a border to appear around that image. 
 would surround the image with a black border.

However, I want the border to only appear after the image has been clicked. My code above does not work and I get the error that **id** is not defined. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: This issue isn't actually all that straight-forward, and would probably require using [local component state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class), to handle the state of which images have borders. Before answering, do you want to make it so that only one image can have a border? Or do you want to make it so that the border of each image can be "toggled" on and off?

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I will look into **local component state** right now. I want it so the border of each image (not limited to one) can be toggled on and off when clicked.

Comment: Sure :) Looks like @HarshMakadia has written up a good example of how to do that

Comment: thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the sample of how you can manage this. You need a state variable to handle it. It will automatically toggle border on click.

```js
const CSSVariables = {
    border : {
        border : '2px solid red'
    },
    noBorder : {
        border : '2px solid transparent'
    },
};

class TestJS extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.applyBorder = this.applyBorder.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            showBorder : false
        }
    }

    applyBorder(){
        this.setState(state => ({ showBorder: !state.showBorder }))
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id="root">
                <img src="https://www.npmjs.com/static/images/avatars/Avatar2.svg" onClick={this.applyBorder} style={this.state.showBorder ? CSSVariables.border : CSSVariables.noBorder}/>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default TestJS;
```

Comment: Good answer! One thing I'd like to point out: when making state updates that depend on the current state, it's considered better practice to use [the callback form of setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), like this: `this.setState(state => ({ showBorder: !state.showBorder }))`

Comment: @kingdaro - Yes you are right since it is asynchronous it's better to update in callback. updated the answer.

Comment: @HarshMakadia thank you for your solution! The toggle on/off border works perfectly for all borders. However, how can I make it so it only changes the border which I select?